Spring Boot: Error uploading image with Axios
Question:
I'm currently working on a Spring Boot application where I have a News entity with fields like title, description, date, and image. Initially, I was able to send data for title, description, and date without any issues. Now, I'm trying to add an image upload feature using Axios, but I'm encountering a 500 error.
Below are my entity and controller classes. Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this issue with Axios? Has anyone encountered and fixed a similar problem before?
Entity Class:
package com.stephanodev.springsecurity.news;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Null;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class News {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Null
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String title;

    private String description;

    @Lob
    private Blob image;

    private String date;
    private String category;
    private String url;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private List<NewsDetail> details;

    // Getters and setters
    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getTitle() { return title; }
    public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }

    public String getDescription() { return description; }
    public void setDescription(String description) { this.description = description; }

    public Blob getImage() { return image; }
    public void setImage(Blob image) { this.image = image; }

    public String getDate() { return date; }
    public void setDate(String date) { this.date = date; }

    public String getCategory() { return category; }
    public void setCategory(String category) { this.category = category; }

    public String getUrl() { return url; }
    public void setUrl(String url) { this.url = url; }

    public List<NewsDetail> getDetails() { return details; }
    public void setDetails(List<NewsDetail> details) { this.details = details; }
}

Controller Class:
package com.stephanodev.springsecurity.news;


@RequestMapping("/api/v1/news")
@RestController
public class NewsController {

    @Autowired
    private NewsRepository newsRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Page<News>> getNews(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page,
                                              @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") int per_page) {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, per_page, Sort.by("id").descending());
        Page<News> news = newsRepository.findAll(pageable);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(news);
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<News>> getAllNews() {
        List<News> allNews = newsRepository.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id"));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(allNews);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<News>> createNews(@RequestBody @Valid List<News> newsList) {
        List<News> savedNews = newsRepository.saveAll(newsList);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(savedNews);
    }
}

I'm encountering a 500 error when attempting to upload an image using Axios. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Http error 500 is a generic error message saying something went wrong. So, my suggestion is to find out what exactly went wrong! Web server error log usually contains some clues. You should also do error handling and logging in your application code.

You can understand it from server log

A separate image upload interface should be provided, and the image upload interface should be separated from the current one. The image entity class should be changed to receive the image path address instead of the blob. When uploading a document, upload the image first, get the image address, and then fill in the image path address and submit it as text.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
